# Bootstrap controls inline alignment?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Other than hacking margins how can I get the following button to display inline with same height as the select in the following code (instead it's dropped down on top margin)?

BootPly -> http://www.bootply.com/73169#

```
<div>           
<h4 class="ilLabel">Select:</h4>
            <select class="form-control" placeholder=".input-medium" height>
                <option value="all">Default</option>
                <option value="s1">Select1</option>
                <option value="s2">Select2</option>
                <option value="s2">Select3</option>    
            </select>   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What version of the bootstrap?

Comment: It's 3 based on the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Select:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select class="form-control">
                <option value="all">Default</option>
                <option value="s1">Select1</option>
                <option value="s2">Select2</option>
                <option value="s2">Select3</option>    
            </select>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```